# iosSlider stair-stepping images on mobile size

Tags: css, mobile, slider

I have an iosSlider that I've switched to retina-sized images recently:

http://www.paperraincoat.com/portfolio/sketches2015/

It looks great at desktop and table size, but the images are stair-stepping at mobile size (<400px). They should line up vertically in the dark area...

Is there any way to set the CSS to fix this? Or some way of turning off iosSlider at a certain size?

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, Jesus finally found it. I had to overwrite that script with two bits of CSS: translate: none; on two separate divs.